# Get rows corresponding to the minimum with pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a table need to groupby by condition:

```
R_num ORG name level
13    Dm   Ad   17
13    Dm   Af   16
```

When i use it gives me `13 Dm Ad 16`, which is like data being manipulated.

```
df1=df.reset_index().groupby(['R_num','ORG']).agg({'name':'first','level':['min']})
```

The result I want is `13 Dm Af 16`, I know probably something wrong with `'name':'first'` but how do i fix this please?

Thank you

Comment: Yea I did, it was my original code, but reset_index has nothing to do with mismatch result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you should use `groupby` and `idxmin`:

```
# df.loc[df.groupby(['R_num','ORG'])['level'].agg('idxmin')]
df.loc[df.groupby(['R_num','ORG'])['level'].idxmin()]

   R_num ORG name  level
1     13  Dm   Af     16
```

Comment: Pfff. I was close but my syntax was off: `df.groupby(['R_num','ORG']).apply(pd.DataFrame.__getitem__, 'level').apply(pd.DataFrame.idxmin)`. When you index a `GroupBy` object like you do above (ie with `['level']`), does that return a plain `Series`?

Comment: @tel Yes, it returns a series with the grouper keys as the index.

Comment: find an alt :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `drop_duplicates` after `sort_values`

```
newdf = df.sort_values('level').drop_duplicates(['R_num','ORG'])
newdf
   R_num ORG name  level
1     13  Dm   Af     16
```